# Unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class c# excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to set Hide=false on an Excel Range object and I keep getting the "Unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class" Exception.  My sheet is not protected and I have no merged cells in the range.

I am doing it like this:

```
    reportSheet.Unprotect("foo");
    int maxUsedRow = reportSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int maxUsedColumn = reportSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    reportSheet.Cells.Range["A5", reportSheet.Cells[maxUsedRow, maxUsedColumn]].Hidden = false;
```

Interestingly:
1. Never anywhere in the code, am I explicitly setting the Hidden property to true, and yet that is what results after the programmatic manipulation.
2. I do not get this error if I do the following, but it also does not work.

```
    int rowNum = 5;
    reportSheet.Rows[rowNum].Hidden = false;
```

Any ideas?

---

I was trying to recreate this behavior in a new project and I realized something in the existing code must have been setting the hidden property.  I debugged through it and found out it was the FormulaHidden property.  Could this be overriding the Hidden property and preventing it from being reset programmatically because it superceeds Hidden?

Comment: Try debugging it and finding out the other range you're passing in, to make sure it's valid.

Comment: I believe to set the `Hidden` property of a `Range` the `Range` must span either the whole Row or the whole Column. I don't believe that in your 1st snippet that you are spanning either the whole Row or Column. Your second snippet looks more likely to work as you are selecting the whole of the 5th Row.

Comment: Winds of Change, I believe the range I pass in in my first snippet is valid.  What would make it invalid?

Comment: Stephen, that is the behavior I have noticed.  As I stated above, it does not cause the error.  However, it also doesn't effect any change. :(

Comment: ...affect any change...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `EntireRow` and `EntireColumn` Property.  As @StephenRoss correctly indicated, you can't really hide a range, per se.  You can hide/unhide rows and columns, but it's not like you can hide Cell B34.  As such, I don't think `Hidden` functions on any entity that is not a row or column.

Here is an example of how you would unhide every row and column from A5 to the end of the data, per your code snippet:

```
int maxUsedRow = reportSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int maxUsedColumn = reportSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

Excelx.Range r = reportSheet.Cells[maxUsedRow, maxUsedColumn];
reportSheet.Range["A5", r.Address].EntireColumn.Hidden = false;
reportSheet.Range["A5", r.Address].EntireRow.Hidden = false;
```